# Can any one help me mail attachment script in php?

Tags: php, file, email, attachment

**Duplicate**: [PHP Attaching an image to an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536838/php-attaching-an-image-to-an-email)

I need mail attachment script in php, and attachment should be multiple files can any one help me?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536838/php-attaching-an-image-to-an-email - libraries mentioned there can all deal with attachments.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.zend.com/zend/spotlight/sendmimeemailpart1.php

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using a framework or want a standalone product, [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com/index.php?pg=phpmailer) is a very good class for sending mail with (multiple) attachments.