# PHP mail() and image display in email client

Tags: php, image, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php image display without download in mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529356/php-image-display-without-download-in-mail)

I have a PHP web application which create wishes card and send them with the PHP `mail()` function.
The wishes card is build with HTML and part of the card are illustrations, those illustrations use jpg images inside an `IMG` tag. The images are hosted on a server so images paths use a complete link (like `http:/domain.com/img.jpg`).

When the card is received, for exemple with thunderbird, it says images are blocked and the user has to click on a button to show the images.
I understand it's a security mesure.
That's still annoying for a whishes card which is meant to be discover with its illustrations.

So, i'm looking for any though, any light, in a way to prevent email clients from blocking images.

Thanks.

Comment: Using as attachment, i see the trick i'll look into it. I'm also thinking about BASE64 but never used and don't know much about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed the image in the email, I strongly recommend something like [phpMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) to do this.

From their documentation:

> Inline Attachments
>
> There is an additional way to add an attachment. If you want to make a
>   HTML e-mail with images incorporated into the desk, it's necessary to
>   attach the image and then link the  tag to it.
>   For example, if you add an image as inline attachment with the CID
>   my-photo, you would access it within the HTML e-mail with &ltimg
>   src="cid:my-photo" alt="my-photo" />.
>
> In detail, here is the function to add an inline attachment:
>   $mail->AddEmbeddedImage(filename, cid, name); By using this function
>   with this example's value above, results in this code:
>   $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('my-photo.jpg', 'my-photo', 'my-photo.jpg ');

Answer (score 2):

Image blocking is done on the receiver's end, by the mail client. There's nothing you can do about it.

It is because of this that you often see the

> Can't see this email? View it here

(Or something similar) at the top of many emails. This is your best alternative.

Comment: Yes i understand that and my card has an online version link.

Comment: @AurélienGrimpard Feel free to accept if it answered your question ;)

Comment: No it doesn't answer my question, i still think there is a solution to the problem. Dale and Jocelyn provide an interesting alternative but i'm searching futher more.

Comment: @AurélienGrimpard Good luck with that