# canvas toDataUrl() how to get base64 result into and out a msql blob field

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, blob, html5-canvas

I want to store the canvas image into a blob field.

on the server side I receive a base64 encoded string from `toDataUrl()`

- What do I have to do to get it into a blob field?
- And how do I display it again in an img tag?

**What code do I need to use?**
The [mysql page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) is not very clear, and I use PDO prepared statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/PDO/MySQL: inserting into MEDIUMBLOB stores bad data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346319/php-pdo-mysql-inserting-into-mediumblob-stores-bad-data)

Comment: @hakre not quite, because the OP is concerning the decoding of the data URI

Comment: @AlvinWong: I'm not so sure about that because in [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651504/how-to-send-html5-canvas-image-with-email) of Richard *that* problem should have been solved already.

Comment: I have everything working in that post, that's true, but I don't know anything about blob. All the posts that I have read are keeping it vague as what to do with the base64.

Comment: why would anyone vote for close, this is annoying, just give some helpfull info

Comment: @Richard: Convert it from base64 to binary with [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) - also [PHP Data-URI to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735414/php-data-uri-to-file)

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* need to store it in blob data, you can do this:

For PHP >=5.2.0, you can use the `data://` stream wrapper to retrieve file from a data uri:

```
$file_in_blob = file_get_contents("data://".$var_containing_the_data_uri);
```

where `$var_containing_the_data_uri` should be replaced by the variable containing the data URI, for example `$_POST['image']`. Then you can insert the `$file_in_blob` to the database.

When you need to display it in a webpage again, you can:

1. write a PHP script that retrieves the blob content according to a GET parameter, and use it as an `src` for the image tag, or
2. directly use the original data URI obtained from `toDataUrl()` as the `src` of the image tag.

If you use method 2, you don't actually need to decode the data URI into blob, but store the data URI directly. (Of course you may be concerned of the data size...)

---

Method 1 example:

Your HTML:

```
<img src="img_from_db.php?img=1" />
```

Your `img_from_db.php`:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png'); // make the browser recognize it as PNG
echo get_image_blob_from_db($_GET['img']); // you may wish to add some checks
```

---

Method 2 example:

```
<img src="<?=get_image_dataURI()?>" />
```

Comment: does $_post['image'] not have to be stripped from the first part in your example(the image info sendwith toDataUrl?

Comment: is the streamwrapper just another way of creating a file just like -- fopen and fwrite. If so then I understand how it works. Do I have to use loadFile for a blobfield or just use it like any other field?

Comment: I have stopped trying to attempt to store it in the database.It is not working for some reason. Also, it is simpeler to store it in the filesystem, because it involves less coding.  If anyone votes to delete this post, I will delete it!