# How to send a picture message (MMS) with PHP

Tags: php, email, attachment, mms

I am currently trying to send a MMS message to a cell phone (via a MMS gateway address) with a PHP script using the mail() function. I want to include a picture in the message.

I haven't found any information specific to sending MMS messages with PHP, and the information that I have found that dealt with sending email attachments was split, with some advising that I use an external package such as Mail_Mime. What would be the best way to send a picture message to a cell phone with a PHP script?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the MMS protocol is a subset of the mail trainsfer protocol? Or that the MMS gateway accepts receival of emails and converts them into MMS protocol for you?

Comment: Yes, if you send a message from an e-mail address to a cell phone mms gateway, then it gets delivered as a picture message (if that answers your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your *carrier* supports receiving email messages and forward them to the handset as MMS, then simply [sending an email with MIME image attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536838/php-attaching-an-image-to-an-email) is sufficient.

However, if you're dealing with an MMS centre (MMSC), then industry standard protocol for application<->MMSC is [`MM7`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MM7_(MMS)#MM7)

Answer (score 1):

Ricky from Twilio here.

I know this is an old question, but for anyone landing here that's looking to accomplish this you can send MMS using our [PHP helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install):

```
<?php

// this line loads the library 
require('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); 

$account_sid = '[AccountSid]'; 
$auth_token = '[AuthToken]'; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token); 

$client->account->messages->create(array( 
    'To' => "+16518675309", 
    'From' => "+14158141829", 
    'Body' => "Hey Jenny! Good luck on the bar exam!", 
    'MediaUrl' => "http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1075/1404618563_3ed9a44a3a.jpg",  
));
```

You can find a few more examples in our [API docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages). Hope that helps!

Comment: Can you clarify what the max upload size is for a video? In the docs is states `Total message size must be under 5MB. An API request with media or collection of media larger than 5MB will fail with an error.`. I'm getting an error in my twilio debugger that states `Retrieved content exceeded the maximum allowed content size.` with a selected solution of `Verify that the specified media is less than 500 KB`. The video I'm attempting to send is about 2MB. Any info would be appreciated, thank you!