# php script to send email with attachement

Tags: php, email, attachment

I have a form where users can edit a certain set of information and attach a file to said information.  If a file is uploaded, I need to email it to certain other people.  I have the following function to handle sending an email with an attachment:

```
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) 
{
    $file = $path.$filename;        
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
    // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header);
}
```

The function DOES send an email (with the correct attachment file name) but the file attached to the email is always a few hundred bytes.  For example, I tried to test by uploading a 45 kb pdf file, and the function sent an email with a pdf file that was 232 bytes.  I've tried using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] as the path as well as a local path (i.e. ./uploads/)... both get the same result.

Does anybody see something obvious that I'm missing... or maybe not so obvious?

Comment: What does the attachment look like when you open it up?

Comment: Do NOT reinvent the wheel. Use PHPMailer

Comment: When i try to open the attached files I get an error saying it can't be opened because it's either not a supported file type or because it's been damaged.  That's for PDFs, images get a similar error from photoshop.

Comment: I already have a mail server set up within IIS.  Don't want to move away from that.

Comment: Can you save the attachment, rename it to .txt, and see what's in there? Are the attachments always the same size?

Comment: [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) isn't a mail server, but a mail client! It gives you everything you need to send an email without headache.

Comment: andrewsi - saved it as a txt file and then opened it.  It was empty

Comment: Either PHPMailer or SwiftMailer will do the job of this in a much neater way. As @WebnetMobile.com says, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I tried to install phpmailer and get the following errors after trying to run the example code: 1) Function ereg() is deprecated in phpmailer.inc.php on like 316 2) undefined variable: from on line 259 3) undefined variable: Encoding on line 271, and 4) cannot acces empty property on line 271.  FYI, my php version is 5.3.10

Comment: switched to swiftmailer.  Seems to be working :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Attaching an image to an email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536838/php-attaching-an-image-to-an-email)